# Naming convention for generated identifiers in C#

Tags: c#, code-generation

In a lot of autogenerated code in Java, the common practice is to preface the name of variables that could potentially clash with user variables with a dollar sign. By convention, manually written code doesn't use dollar signs. However, in C# that character isn't valid in identifiers. Is there a standard practice for naming generated identifiers? I'm currently prefixing them with a double-underscore, which I believe is often used in C.

Sometimes you want to generate a superclass with certain functionality, and allow the subclass to wrap it up in a neat package. That's when this would apply.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but before you run too far down this path, you should learn about partial classes which are the C# solution for handling extensibility for generated code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(VS.80).aspx

Comment: You should never prefix generated identifiers with double underscore in C. It may be a "common" practice, but it's very wrong. Double underscore is reserved for _implementation_ (e.g. for language extensions, or private identifiers in the haders).

Comment: @Kirk: partial classes do not prevent name clashes, however. If one body of a partial class declares a method with a particular signature, for example, no other body can redefine it. It has more to do with convenient separation of build artifacts.

Comment: @Pavel, yes, I understand partial classes do not prevent name clashes.  That is exactly why I prefaced my *comment* with "Doesn't answer your question"...  :)

Comment: Pavel: I think I was wrong about it being common practice in C. I have done very little in C, but I did remember the double-underscores being weird.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the *standard* convention is in this case, but since [C# accepts Unicode characters in identifers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2006/02/13/530799.aspx), you could just pick a few arbitrary Unicode characters to *virtually* guarantee that no names will clash.

What are the odds of any variable starting with ꉜꈅ⣎, for instance?